# What is Fisher Information defined on?

Tags: probability, statistics, information-theory, fisher-information

The definition of Fisher Information on wikipedia is:
\begin{equation}
I(\theta) = E_\theta \left[\left(\dfrac{\partial}{\partial\theta}\ln p\left(X;\theta\right)\right)^2\right]
\end{equation}
Inside is a probability distribution.
But in many places, it is defined as
\begin{equation}
I(\theta) = E_\theta \left[\left(\dfrac{\partial}{\partial\theta}\ln p\left(\theta;X\right)\right)^2\right]
\end{equation}
Inside is the likelihood function.

I was always warned to be careful about the difference between likelihood function and probability density function. So why they seems totally equivalent here?

Evenif they are equivalent, I found the likelihood seems easier to understand as the variant is always
$\theta$, and it can directly link to the MLE estimation. But with the probability function I cannot really understand anything from it.
Why would people define the Fisher information with probability function at all? What does it reveal? Or these 2 definitons makes 0 difference and people just write as  will?